# Django ListView with pagination and grouping

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-orm

Let's suppose I have 2 models: **Artist** and **Album** (with albums having a foreign key relationship to **Artist**)... now I want to display all the albums using a paginated `ListView`, BUT I want to display them grouped by artist. I know that django provides a powerful tag: [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) ...but of course I can't use it if I'm paginating my results, because some artist albums may not be already retrieved from the database... so my question is: how can I accomplish this using Django's ORM?

The goal is to print something like:

> ```
> Artist 1
> - album 1
> - album 2
> - album 3
>
> Artist 2
> - album 1
> - album 2
>
> ...
> ```

Comment: So you want to display albums - grouped by artist, but not show the artist name? How do you want the results to be sorted? By artist name, by album name? Does one album only have one artist?

Comment: I want also to display the artist name of course, and an album has only one artist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you can fetch related albums for that artist:

```
<ul>
{% for artist in object_list %}
   <li> {{ artist }}
   <ul>
   {% for album in artist.album_set.all %}
       <li>{{ album }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: but this will trigger a query for each artist... I would like to avoid multiple queries

Comment: You can avoid this by doing a `select_related` in your ListView

Comment: no, I solved... I have to use `prefetch_related` since I'm using an inverse relationship! The query is: Artist.objects.prefetch_related('albums') ...anyway thanks for, the help, I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted ;)